# Open source, modern PHP project management system with many themes

Tags: gratis, open-source, web-apps, php, project-management

I'm looking for

1. Free and open source php/mysql project management system that can be installed on shared hosting, self hosted solution of course, on my server
2. Updated and with many themes, because my client wants to use a black theme
3. Extremely easy to use because my client is an old architect, I don't want to spend hours teaching him how to use it
4. Support for many languages is a huge plus, the client speaks english fairly well but his native language is arabic and he's francophone, his preferred language is french
5. Integration with wordpress is a huge plus since his main website runs on wordpress
6. Support for different file type uploads, including autocad, since as an architect, his projects are all autocad.
7. Support for many client at once (multiple private projects)
8. Messaging and all the features that one would need in a project management software
9. Billing management I guess, not sure, if it exists it's a bonus.

So mainly, a client contacts him, the architect accepts the project, he starts working on it, they could check on the progress, talk to each other and notify the client when done.

Fengoffice seems so out of date, no themes, and extremely hard to use, even I find it hard to use it, how about a 65 years old man? My teammate tested http://collabtive.o-dyn.de/ and told me it suffers from huge problems.

Theming is so important because you know clients value UX above all else. If I cannot find a project management system as easy to use as I want, I might have to ask the client for much more money just to develop an in house solution.

I don't really like what I see on google. Simplicity is everything. The system has to be developed for people like architects in mind, not programmers, no wiki, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Traq](https://traq.io).

There is a nice user interface of the traq development availabe at https://bugs.traq.io/traq/tickets